# Recycling views, listview inside scrollview

Tags: android, listview, view, scrollview, recycle

I am aware of `recycling of views in LiveView`, I am also aware that we cannot `have a listview as a child of scroll view`, which just scrambles the scrolling up.

I know the `work around of using LinearLayout` or any other viewgroup and add components to it. Which is much feasible, but I like my app tuned, and I `want to recycle views` when I am implementing the workaround.

If I inflate once and try to add that view, an exception occures and asks me `first call removeView()` on parent.

Can any one tell me other workaround if there's one, or how can I implement recycling in this scenario ?

Comment: I can't see from your post what you are trying to work around. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to disable the scrolling of a ListView by creating a custom ListView component and overriding the dispatchTouchEvent() method.  This will let you embed a ListView within a ScrollView container.  Take a look at my answer for:

[Adapter for a List displayed inside a Scroll View, non-Scrolling List View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772540/adapter-for-a-list-displayed-inside-a-scroll-view-non-scrolling-list-view/7772658#7772658)

Comment: Ok, that's one. But is there anyway I can recycle views on demand, outside a listview ?