# Adapter for a List displayed inside a Scroll View, non-Scrolling List View?

Tags: android, list, listview, scrollview, adapter

In the app I am currently building I have been synchronizing ListViews with unbound Lists of data via BaseAdapter. This has been working so far but now I need to have a list of data inside a ScrollView. The problem with putting a ListView inside a ScrollView is that both views scroll and it make the activity difficult to navigate. From what I've read online the consensus seems to be that ListViews should never be put inside of scroll views for this reason, and that a LinearLayout or TableLayout should be used instead.

My quesion is this: Can any one tell me either how to get rid of the Scrolling Feature on a ListView or how to synchronize a List of data with a LinearLayout or a TableLayout through an adapter?

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own custom ListView component and then override the [dispatchTouchEvent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) method:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    int action = event.getAction();
    if (!scrollEnabled) {
        event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
        super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        return true; 
    }

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

In these kinds of situations though, what I've done in the past is have a separate vertical LinearLayout for my list and manually added TextViews via code to it, making it look similar to a listview.

Comment: John thank you very much for your reply. Your code did stop the ListView from Scrolling, however now I have the problem that my parent layout is not "measuring" my ListView when it's height is set to wrap content. I believe this is because ListViews are  designed to include lists that are longer than the layouts they are being added to. Any suggestion for getting around this problem?

Comment: You have 2 options:  1)  Set the ListView height manually (to a height either calculated in code or just set to a set value, like 200dp).  Option 2)  Don't use a listview at all, just add TextViews inside of a LinearLayout container.  Because a listview technically has a depth of infinity, it will never be able to use wrap_content.

Comment: @JohnLeehey I am facing the same issue but if I set listview height depending on the list items than it will work but in that situation recycling of the views will not be possible as all the list item will be visible at the same time, do you have any solution for that?